# Elasticsearch 5 how to start writing a native Java plugin

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am currently trying to write an Elasticsearch plugin (mainly for testing purposes), and I am struggling with the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/plugin-authors.html)  which simply states:

> These examples provide the bare bones needed to get started. For more information about how to write a plugin, we recommend looking at the plugins listed in this documentation for inspiration.

So basically, after finding a few tutorials (which kind of disagree with each other besides the maven part), see http://david.pilato.fr/blog/2016/07/27/creating-a-plugin-for-elasticsearch-5-dot-0-using-maven/ and http://jfarrell.github.io (they don't inherit the same classes).

I am actually stuck where to start, what components are available from the core elasticsearch dependency, and how should I load my plugin. (I know I can look into it by testing and retro engineering, I just wondered if anyone had good tips regarding the topic).

For now my code just looks like:

```
public class MyPlugin extends Plugin implements NativeScriptFactory{
  //overriden methods
}
```

Where should I go from there?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@asttouf

I recently wrote a plugin to EL 2.3.x (https://github.com/betorcs/elastic-recurring-plugin). It was hard to find a documentation saying steps to follow to write it. I needed to google at lot to find some references.

I'm listing some projects I used as reference, i hope they can help you.

- https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/tree/master/plugins/ingest-attachment
- https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments
- https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-writing-a-plugin
- http://www.flax.co.uk/blog/2016/01/27/fun-frustration-writing-plugin-elasticsearch-ontology-indexing/

**EDITED**

More references:

- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/modules-scripting-native.html
- https://www.elastic.co/blog/writing-your-own-ingest-processor-for-elasticsearch

Plugin updated to support ES 5.0, check out https://github.com/betorcs/elastic-recurring-plugin/tree/5.0

Comment: I will definitely give it a look. I'm just looking for es 5 though... Thanks mate

Comment: I see, I'm changing it to give support to es 5. Stay tuned.

Comment: Thanks a lot I'll also see with your links if I can figure the shenanigans happening in Elastic

Comment: Awesome, so for an ES5 plugin, you would suggest to build rather with gradle than maven, correct?

Comment: I follow two projects using gradle, I also prefer gradle. And notice ES 5.0 You should use gradle 2.13.

Comment: Guys, any documentation on building filter or aggregation plugins?